# What is the difference between setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled and setHomeButtonEnabled?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to enable the home button in the Action bar. I'm using this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

In this I'm using `setHomeButtonEnabled` and `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` to put a back mark at icon in ActionBar. If I use only `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` then also will it work? Is there a need to set `setHomeButtonEnabled` to true?

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

For what you want to do, `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` is enough.
For the difference :
`actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` will just make the icon clickable, with the color at the background of the icon as a feedback of the click. 
`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` will make the icon clickable and add the `<` at the left of the icon.

Comment: When only `setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` is set, will it still call `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: I think so but I didn't check.

Comment: For the record, I checked and `setHomeButtonEnabled(true)` **does** still call `onOptionsItemSelected` and can be captured the same way where `item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home`. So the only difference is that `<` icon.

Comment: By using actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) the application navigate back by clicking the application title. How to avoid application title click for up navigation.

Answer (score 9):

As Android says:

```
- setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean showHome)
  // Set whether to include the application home affordance in the action bar.
  // (and put a back mark at icon in ActionBar for "up" navigation)

 -setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean enabled)
  // Enable or disable the "home" button in the corner of the action bar.
  // (clickable or not)
```

It should be quite clear i think