# Android Home button on Action Bar Does Not Appear

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I came across this strange problem where the Home button on toolbar is not showing.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/design_navigation_elevation"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="my.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
        <include layout="@layout/fab"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

I have another app using the same method, which is working fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer"/>
```

Which it has a default icon:

[image]

And take a look at this blog: [**codetheory.in (web.archive)**](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221060827/http://codetheory.in/difference-between-setdisplayhomeasupenabled-sethomebuttonenabled-and-setdisplayshowhomeenabled)

**Which says:**

> **setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean enabled)**
>
> This method is similar to the previous one(`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean showHomeAsUp`)) actually, except that the
>   left-facing caret ***doesn’t show up unless the
>   [`android:parentActivityName`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent) is specified.***

Instead, try to use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabl‌​‌​ed(true);
```

Then, ***it should work without that `Drawer` i guess***.because it has a default icon.

Check the results without `Drawer` with my suggested code: [image]

Somehow, you don't need that.

Comment: Thanks. The strange thing is when I use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabl‌​‌​ed(true); the left arrow button appears now. But since this is the main screen, I'd like a home carrot button instead of a back arrow button.

Comment: Hmm, like i guessed about that home screen, read this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492280/what-is-the-difference-between-setdisplayhomeasupenabled-and-sethomebuttonenable

Comment: And the thing is, you are or the user is in the **main Screen/Activity**, so, where are you trying to go ? `stack` ? :)

Comment: What does a Carrot button?

Comment: Perhaps this icon? `<` that's the only differences between these two, that icon is deprecated btw.Of course you are trying to use that with this one: `AppCompatActivity` .Instead, try to use `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_24dp_black40);`

Comment: The navigationView does not display the default hamburger icon though.

Comment: Yeah well, that's what i was trying to tell you, i was wondering what is the purpose of using that in the `MainActivity/Screen` :) you don't need that