# Button may produce null pointer exception (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio, nullpointerexception

new to Android Studio, and I thought I was doing okay, but ran into an error last night that I just can't seem to fix despite all my best googling efforts. A button on one of my activities 'may produce java.lang.NullPointerException', except it keeps failing every time it's pushed. It may just be something as simple as ordering a line of code in the wrong place etc, but I'm so new to Android studio I don't really know where I'm going wrong.

```
   public class searchPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button goBackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goBackButton);

    goBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(searchPage.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
     });
```

Here's the XML

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/goBackButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

And the Manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.onein.mobilefinalapp">

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".searchPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_page"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MoviePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_movie_page"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

Here's the activity_search_page.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <include layout="@layout/content_search_page" />

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you need any other information, please let me know.

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT - removed duplicate button, and adding in activity_search_page.xml

Comment: why do you have two Buttons with same id `goBackButton` ?

Comment: The exception stack trace will be helpful.

Comment: Share activity_search_page.xml also

Comment: You cant have two buttons with the same id. Please show the error log.

Comment: You are still not defining where the `goBackButton` really exists? is that inside `content_search_page` ? If so then post that full `XML`.

Comment: What is the name of that xml, in which you have put the button goBackButton ?, also put entire xml file here for better help

Answer (score 4):

> Method invocation 'setOnClickListener' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' less...
>
> This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.

This is only a **warning** because `findViewById` will return `null` if the given id cannot be found in the layout.

You can safely ignore it if you know for sure that the id is in the layout you are using, or you can ignore it with an assertion (And possibly an `@Nullable` annotation).

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.someId);
assert v != null;
v.setOnClickListener(...);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this. Still crashing my app when I run it and click the button. Just says the app has stopped working

Comment: And the logcat should tell you why, just like an other NullPointerException in Java

Comment: thanks, works for me! though i'm a bit confused, I get the NullPointerException error OP pointed out if I don't use an "assert v != null" statement before setting the click listener. 

@cricket_007 could you provide a little more insight why?  i'm under the impression assert statements are use to print errors on trying out a condition, rather than control flow.  i've changed my "assert v != null" to "if(v != null)" to make more sense in my head haha

Comment: It's not an error. It's a warning. Static code analysis over an assert statement is going to say the variable isn't null on the following lines

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out correctly by@cricket007 
This is a warning that in case if no resource is found then, null is returned which actually makes the app crash.

Some ways to solve this problem:

1) Use the command

```
assert object_name != null
```

or simply do `alt+enter`, it's among one of the top suggestions by the android studio.

2) Use

```
if(object!=null)
```

3)
Edit: This is a working method but a bad practice, a simple if is preferred over this.

Use `try` and `catch` block (Java's way of handling errors.)

```
try{
    your entire code here;
}
catch(Exception e){
    what to do when exception happens
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to Stack committee, so please feel free to edit the answer for better, and let me know should I add a gist of code, where I have implemented or not?Thank you.

Comment: Try catching a nullpointerexception is bad practice in my experience

Comment: @cricket_007 should I delete it in edit or add tag not recommended?How is it done over here on stack overflow?

Comment: It's your post, but I'm just pointing out that a simple if not null check is the preferred Java pattern for dealing with controlled nullpointerexception

Comment: Done as suggested by you cricket_007.
Thank you for the suggestion, I learnt thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `Button` needs to be in `activity_search_page.xml` file for `findViewById()` to work.

Second, I think you want the back button functionality, in that case

1. Remove the code related to `Button`
2. Add `toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
3. Add below code

   ```
   toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
               startActivity(new Intent(searchPage.this, MainActivity.class));
         }
   });
   ```
4. Optional, use `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_own_back_button_drawable_here);` to use your own drawable.

[This may help as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492280/what-is-the-difference-between-setdisplayhomeasupenabled-and-sethomebuttonenable)