# Nullpointer exception warning when setting adapter to a listView

Tags: java, android

My code is as follows:

```
public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView listView;
        ItemAdapter adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.attaction_list);

            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(new Item("a", "a", a));
            items.add(new Item("b", "b", b));
            items.add(new Item("c", "c", c));

            adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, items, R.color.event);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            if(adapter != null) {
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Andoid Studio editor indicates that `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` may cause a nullpointer exception. Could anyone explain where that warning comes from and how to fix it?

Comment: The ItemAdapter class is my customized adapter class which extends ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Can you show ItemAdapter and XML layout attaction_list ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button may produce null pointer exception (Android Studio)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204297/button-may-produce-null-pointer-exception-android-studio)

Comment: @MikeM. But no one in that question actually provided a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, they did. Anyway, it's just a warning. Make sure the `View` is in the layout, and then ignore it. Or put unnecessary null checks everywhere. If your `View` isn't in the layout, then it _should_ fail with an Exception. You can't change the fact that `findViewById()` can return `null`.

Comment: I added an if(listView != null) check, the warning disappears. Thanks mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at developer document at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

> **findViewById**
>
> `View findViewById (int id)`
>
> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that
>   was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
>
> `Parameters`
>
> id   int
>
> `Returns`
>
> View
>     The view if found **or null otherwise**.

*where that warning comes from*

So you see that the variable `listView` may be null after the execution of `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);`. So you get the warning!

*how to fix it*

You may provide the null-checking expression in the if-condition as follows:

```
if(adapter != null && listView !=null ) {
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sanjeev, I understand that the id may not be found and therefore returns null. But my question is how to fix that. ps. I just reloaded the page and read ur new edition. It seems working, thx!